# Selecting colors which are evenly spaced around a color wheel

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

In the following diagram

[image]

I would like to assign colors to the rectangles in each layer with colors from around a color wheel so that the colors in adjacent layers are separated by 144 degrees. For context `$b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}b_{4}b_{5}$` is a string of elements from a Boolean algebra. The horizontal position indicates the "location" of the element. Here is the code

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (b1)  at (-1.0, 0.25) {$b_{1}$};
    \node (b2)  at  (-1.0, 0.75) {$b_{2}$};
    \node (b3)  at (-1.0, 1.25) {$b_{3}$};
    \node (b4)  at  (-1.0, 1.75) {$b_{4}$};
    \node (b5)  at (-1.0, 2.25) {$b_{5}$};
    \draw (0, 0) -- ( 3.5, 0);
    \fill[blue!50!white]    (0, 0) rectangle (1.0, 0.5);
    \fill[green!50!white]   (1.5, 0.5) rectangle (2.5, 1.0);
    \fill[red!50!white]     (0.75, 1.0) rectangle (1.75, 1.5);
    \fill[red!50!white]     (3.0, 1.0) rectangle (3.5, 1.5);
    \fill[purple!50!white]    (0.75, 1.5) rectangle (1.5, 2.0);
    \fill[yellow!50!white]   (0.75, 2.0) rectangle (1.5, 2.5);
\end{document}
```

If there is a better method for accomplishing this task, feel free to mention it.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the package `ninecolors`? You could also use the `hsb` model from the `xcolor` package and for each step increase the hue by, for example 10 degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hsb` color model and increase the hue by 144 degrees for each row. But you need to load the `xcolor` package with the `rgb` option before loading the `tikz` package on order to make this work.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\i*144,360)}
        \definecolor{current}{Hsb}{\pgfmathresult,.5,1}
        \node[fill=current, inner sep=10pt] at (\i, 0) {};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The same than Jasper bur on a weel:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle(2);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
            \pgfmathparse{mod(\i*144,360)}
            \definecolor{current}{Hsb}{\pgfmathresult,.5,1}
            \node[fill=current, inner sep=6pt] at (\i*36:2) () {};
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing how to put items in a circle. The diagrams I need are more like the diagram in my question.